# Trying to get all possible combinations from an unknown number of list of strings

Tags: c#, combinations, nested-lists

Given a list of lists I am looking to create all possible combinations.

Example:

I have a list which holds 3 lists

List 1: Apple, Banana, Pear

List 2: Bed, Chair

List 3: Ben, Bob, Carl, Phil

From this I would expect to end up with a List of combinations

Apple_Bed_Ben

Apple_Bed_Bob

Apple_Bed_Carl

Apple_Bed_Phil

Apple_Chair_Ben

Apple_Chair_Bob

Apple_Chair_Carl

Apple_Chair_Phil

Banana_Bed_Ben

Banana_Bed_Bob

...

I don't know if I am missing something but I have been going in circles for hours now.

If I knew there would only ever be three lists I know I could just use nested for loops going through building the combination string but here there could be any number of lists.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to get this done?

This is what i currently have:

```
public class ChildrenNames
{
    public string parentName;
    public int numberOfNames;
    public List<string> childrenNames = new List<string>();
}

public class Combination
{
    public bool selected = true;
    public string name;
}

List<Combination> GetAllCombinations()
{
    List<Combination> allCombinations = new List<Combination>();
    List<ChildrenNames> listOfChildren = new List<ChildrenNames>();

    //Create list of children names for each parent object
    for (int p = 0; p < parentObjects.Count; p++)
    {
        ChildrenNames cn = new ChildrenNames();

        for (int c = 0; c < parentObjects[p].transform.childCount; c++)
            cn.childrenNames.Add(parentObjects[p].transform.GetChild(c).name);

        cn.parentName = parentObjects[p].name;
        cn.numberOfNames = cn.childrenNames.Count;
        listOfChildren.Add(cn);
    }

    for (int l = 0; l < listOfChildren.Count; l++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < listOfChildren[l].numberOfNames; c++)
        {
            if (l == 0)
            {
                for (int p  = 0; p  < listOfChildren.Count; p ++)
                {
                    Combination combination = new Combination();
                    combination.name = listOfChildren[l].childrenNames[c];
                    allCombinations.Add(combination);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < allCombinations.Count; i++)
                    allCombinations[i].name += "_" + listOfChildren[l].childrenNames[c];
            }
        }

    }

    return allCombinations;
}
```

This creates the correct number of combinations but for example throws out

Apple_Bed_Chair_Ben_Bob_Carl_Phil

I understand why this is happening but not how I can change this to get the expected result.

Comment: You've been going in circles for hours now but still came up with no single line of code?

Comment: @Programmer Yes which is how I ended up here, Everything I tried didn't work.

I have my lists, I can iterate through them, but i don't know how to do it in a way that I can build up the strings of combinations.

Comment: Post the code that didn't work. Make sure to edit it into your question and explain how it didn't work

Comment: You can solve this in a one liner using Linq. Show some effort on your part.

Comment: @Programmer Thanks updated the post as you suggested

Comment: @InBetween sorry I have never used Linq and wouldn't know where to start! any suggestions?

Comment: You can start [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq/).

Comment: You are looking for `Apple_Bed_Ben`...`Banana_Bed_Ben`... and `Pear_Bed_Ben` combinations? It must start with item in List1? For example, no `Bed_Bed_Apple`  right?

Comment: @Programmer correct, so the order will always be elementFromFirst List_ElementFromSecondList_... and so on.

Im looking in to using Linq currently but having no luck.

Comment: I have answer without link if you are interested

Comment: @Programmer yes please, I'm getting nowhere here

Comment: I provided the `for` loop and `linq` version. That should do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep track of the column for each of the lists in order for it to work properly.

```
public List<string> ZipStringLists(params List<string>[] lists)
{
    var columnNo = new int[lists.Length];
    var resultingList = new List<string>();
    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    while (columnNo[0] < lists[0].Count)
    {
        // Combine the items into one: Apple + Banana + Pear = AppleBananaPear
        for (int i = 0; i < lists.Length; i++)
        {
            var listElement = lists[i];
            // columnNo[i] contains which column to write out for the individual list
            stringBuilder.Append(listElement[columnNo[i]]);
        }

        // Write out the result and add it to a result list for later retrieval
        var result = stringBuilder.ToString();
        resultingList.Add(result);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        stringBuilder.Clear();

        // We increment columnNo from the right to the left
        // The next item after AppleBedBen is AppleBedBob
        // Overflow to the next column happens when a column reaches its maximum value 
        for (int i = lists.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (++columnNo[i] == lists[i].Count 
                    && i != 0 /* The last column overflows when the computation finishes */)
            {
                // Begin with 0 again on overflow and continue to add to the next column
                columnNo[i] = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                // No overflow -> stop
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    return resultingList;
}
```

Usage:

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string> { "Apple", "Banana", "Pear" };
List<string> list2 = new List<string> { "Bed", "Chair" };
List<string> list3 = new List<string> { "Ben", "Bob", "Carl", "Phil" };

ZipStringLists(list1, list2, list3);
```

Comment: This works!

I Made minor changes but works as expected thank you!

Comment: Just to clarify the changes i made:

In Unity it was saying stringBuilder did not contain a definition for Clear(); Because of this I removed that and just had a string called name, this also made it easier for me to format the string as I wanted.

also because my lists were lists within a list,  i changed (params List<string>[] lists) to simply (List<string>[] lists). with this I went through my list of lists and built up an array to pass to the function.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a fairly generic solution that accepts any number of lists to incrementally build up the combinations.   It's short, though not necessarily as optimal as other solutions as it builds intermediate lists:

```
    public List<string> FindCombinations(params List<string>[] lists)
    {
        List<string> combinations = lists[0];

        for (int i = 1; i < lists.Length; i++)
        {
            List<string> newCombinations = new List<string>(combinations.Count * lists[i].Count);
            combinations.ForEach(s1 => lists[i].ForEach(s2 => newCombinations.Add($"{s1}_{s2}")));
            combinations = newCombinations;
        }

        return combinations;
    }
```

Usage:

```
   List<string> combinations = FindCombinations(list1, list2, list3, list4, list5...)
```